# Query does not filter results on another field

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to use a field (Combo Box) on MS Access in order to filter the results available on another Combo Box field.
The main purpose of this operation is to show only records of the exact user, which one can choose on the "user" combo box. To do so, I use a query.
No matter what I do, it just does not filter the results.
However, if I open the query, it shows a table with correctly filtered results.
And if I type in manually user ID, it also works fine.
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: What are you doing right now? There's not enough info in your description to piece together the details of your current set up

Comment: Basically it's an invoicing system. Two tables, one with "users", one with "services". They share together "user_id" on services table and "id" on users table. That's how they are linked together. I hope this is enough :) Thanks!

Comment: Not quite enough. When you say `To do so, I use a query.` what does that mean? What does the query say? How is it linked to the first combobox?

Comment: Forgive me, the query is the following:

SELECT ODS.IDODS, cmbDirettrice.Direttrice, ODS.ServData
FROM ((cmbClienti INNER JOIN ODS ON cmbClienti.IDCliente = ODS.FattIDCliente) INNER JOIN cmbDirettrice ON ODS.IDODS = cmbDirettrice.IDODS) INNER JOIN Clienti ON cmbClienti.IDCliente = Clienti.IDCliente
WHERE (((Clienti.IDCliente)=[ID Cliente: ]))
ORDER BY ODS.ServData;

It is linked with the following criteria: [Forms]![Ricevute]![ric_cliente_id] - where ric_cliente_id is the same as IDCliente (IDUser in English, which is the same as FattIDCliente - they all share the same ID). Thank you!